# Implement custom Huggingface dataset with data downloaded from s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, huggingface-datasets

In order to implement a custom Huggingface dataset I need to implement three methods:

```
from datasets import DatasetBuilder, DownloadManager

class MyDataset(DatasetBuilder):
    def _info(self):
        ...

    def _split_generator(self, dl_manager: DownloadManager):
        '''
        Method in charge of downloading (or retrieving locally
        the data files), organizing them according to the splits
        and defining specific arguments for the generation process
        if needed.
        '''
        ...

    def _generate_examples():
        ...
```

Now, in the `_split_generator` method I need to download a CSV file from S3 (a private bucket, one needs keys to access it). This file will be then further processed once it's been downloaded.

Do you know if there is a way to use the parameter `dl_manager` to download it? I guess I can download the file with some other methods/external libraries, but I'm wondering if I can do it with Huggingface's `datasets` objects and functionalities.

In [this repo](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/tree/master/datasets) you can see many examples of custom datasets. For instance, the data used to build the *amazon us reviews* is downloaded from `https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/tsv/amazon_reviews_us_" + name + ".tsv.gz"` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/6face39e5c3e04893150156741e522f5b803a15c/datasets/amazon_us_reviews/amazon_us_reviews.py#L160)). This is a public link though, and it can be accessed by everybody. Instead, I would like to use a `Downloadmanager` object to download my private data from S3.

Answer (score 0):

`datasets` provides some class to download things from S3 (and other Cloud providers) : https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.4.0/en/filesystems

So you can do something like :

```py
def _split_generators(self, dl_manager):
    s3 = datasets.filesystems.S3FileSystem()

    _, f = os.path.split(MY_S3_URI)
    s3.get(MY_S3_URI, os.path.join(CACHE_DIR, f))

    return [
        datasets.SplitGenerator(name=datasets.Split.ALL, gen_kwargs={"filepath": os.path.join(CACHE_DIR, f)}),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found `DownloadManager` has a `download_custom` method just for this.

https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/builder_classes#datasets.DownloadManager.download_custom

From their example:

```py
downloaded_files = dl_manager.download_custom(
    's3://my-bucket/data.zip',
    custom_download_for_my_private_bucket
)
```

Note you can combine this with `extract` to get the analogous behavior of `download_and_extract` with your custom download function.

```py
extracted_path = dl_manager.extract(
    dl_manager.download_custom(
        's3://my-bucket/data.zip', 
        custom_download_for_my_private_bucket
    )
)
```